# Accessing a private method in javascript

Tags: javascript, private-methods

The following is my javascript code for accessing a private method. But it is not working. I receive a `TypeError: string is not a function` message. Can anyone please help me?

Here is my code:

```
function Boy(firstName,lastName) {
    this.fisrtName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName ;
    var ladyLove = "Angelina";

    var returnLove = function() {
        return ladyLove;
    };

    this.sayLoud = function(){
        return returnLove();
    };
}

var achilles = new Boy("Bradley","Pitt");
var sayNow = achilles.sayLoud();
console.log(sayNow());
```

Comment: Where in the code is the error???

Comment: There is nothing private in javascript, just different scopes ?

Comment: All the code just changed completely.  I'm confused.

Comment: @JamesMontagne: I goofed up an edit, restored it. (My beautifier is a little buggy at times)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sayLoud()` returns `Angelina` - which is a `String`, not a `function`.

You probably just want to go for:

```
console.log(sayNow);
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using a string as a function, you should use `console.log(sayNow);`

Explained:

```
var achilles = new Boy("Bradley","Pitt"); // Will create a new object
var sayNow = achilles.sayLoud(); // call sayLoud(), return string
console.log(sayNow); // output the string
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var achilles = new Boy("Bradley","Pitt");
var sayNow = achilles.sayLoud; 
console.log(sayNow());
```